# Spring KafkaTemplate not handling errors on partition number

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Hi i have a simple demo app that sends message on a Kafka Queue.

This is the portion of the code that i execute:

```
kafkaTemplate.send("topic", partitionId, "asd", jsonInput);
future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
            System.out.println("Sent message=[" + result.getProducerRecord().value() +
                    "] with offset=[" + result.getRecordMetadata().offset() + "]");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to send message due to : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
```

While tryng to develop this demo i have tried using a partitionId bigger than the partition size of my Topic to see if i got an error.
But the code doesn't enter in the onFailure and stays stuck in the kafkaTemplate.send call. I can see this because there is no logs and the api call that i make to call this demo service stays stuck. How can i catch errors of partition Size?

Comment: It should at least log with an error like `LEADER_NOT_KNOWN` or `UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set the partition in the producer send call. Assuming you don't want to use `DefaultPartitioner`, you should instead define a `Partitioner` interface, and set this in your ProducerConfig.

Then you should mod the partition value by the number of partitions the topic really has.

Otherwise, by default, Kafka automatically partitions the data, and you don't need to set the ID at all.

Answer (score 0):

The send will eventually time out based on the `max.block.ms` property, which defaults to 60 seconds.

You can reduce the property, or wait 60 seconds.